# Pandas drop duplicates but keep maximum value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure variations of this question have been asked, but I have a very specific scenario that I need to execute efficiently.

Imagine a dataframe outlined like so:

| Date | Value | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-29 | 100 | 1 |
| 2021-03-29 | 50 | 1 |
| 2021-03-28 | 90 | 1 |
| 2021-03-28 | 100 | 1 |
| 2021-03-27 | 110 | 1 |
| 2021-03-29 | 100 | 2 |
| 2021-03-29 | 50 | 2 |
| 2021-03-28 | 90 | 2 |
| 2021-03-28 | 100 | 2 |
| 2021-03-27 | 110 | 2 |

What you'll notice is that in this dataframe, there are duplicate "date"s for each "id". This is a reporting error, so what I'd like to do, is go through each "id" and remove one of the duplicate dates rows completely.

I would like to KEEP the version of each duplicate date, that had a greater "value".

My ideal resulting dataframe would look like so:

| Date | Value | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-29 | 100 | 1 |
| 2021-03-28 | 100 | 1 |
| 2021-03-27 | 110 | 1 |
| 2021-03-29 | 100 | 2 |
| 2021-03-28 | 100 | 2 |
| 2021-03-27 | 110 | 2 |

I am also doing this on a relatively large dataset (~2.5 million records) so I'd like to find a solution that's relatively fast (something better than just for-looping and doing this manually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest sorting by descending `value`, and using `drop_duplicates`, dropping the values that have duplicate `Date` and `id` values. The first value (e.g. the highest), will be kept by default

```
df.sort_values("Value", ascending = False).drop_duplicates(subset=["Date", "id"], keep="first")

        Date  Value  id
4 2021-03-27    110   1
9 2021-03-27    110   2
0 2021-03-29    100   1
3 2021-03-28    100   1
5 2021-03-29    100   2
8 2021-03-28    100   2
```

You can re-sort to get the ordering in your desired output by chaining `.sort_values(["id", "Date"])` to the end if you want

Comment: Wow I was thinking wayy too hard about this, this solves my problem perfectly, thank you lol